# Access different subnet IPs on two different interfaces

Tags: networking, router, routing, iptables, dhcp

I'm trying to configure my Raspberry Pi to give me access to devices connected either of eth0 or wlan1.

Desired function is this:

- User connects to RPi AP via wlan1 and is given an IP (192.168.4.x)
- Separate device with connects to RPi via eth0 and is given an IP (192.168.5.x)
- User can access configuration interface of eth0 connected device via its local IP address

I've used dnsmasq to set up the DHCP servers on each interface and they are quite happily providing IPs;

```
# dnsmasq.conf
interface=wlan1
dhcp-range=wlan1,192.168.4.2,192.168.4.99,24h

interface=eth0
dhcp-range=eth0,192.168.5.1,192.168.5.99,24h

listen-address=::1,127.0.0.1,192.168.5.1,192.168.4.1
```

I've also update my iptables to forward traffic between the interfaces;

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan1 -j ACCEPT
```

I am still a bit lost, however, when it comes to actually accessing the different IPs. I believe I need some routes set up, but I'm struggling to figure out how to implement this exactly.

Pinging a 192.168.4.x and 192.168.5.x IP via wlan0 connection:
[image]

And from a ...4.x and ...5.x from eth0 connection:
[image]

iptables and netstat outputs:

```
pi@rak-gateway:~ $ sudo iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
pi@rak-gateway:~ $ netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0
192.168.4.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan1
192.168.5.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your update.

The first thing I would suggest is that you fix your `eth0` DHCP range to start at `192.168.5.2` - it currently seems to start at `192.168.5.1`.

The next thing to post is the routing table of a device connected via `eth0`, and the routing table of a device connected via `wlan1`.

Make sure both devices have successfully performed DHCP and have addresses in the subnets you're expecting before getting their routing tables.

Comment: I tried disabling all firewall rules, no difference. I've updated my post with some more detail on pings, but essentially I cannot ping anything (rpi or connected devices) on the 192.168.5.x subnet from 192.168.4.x subnet and vice-versa.

Comment: @Kureigu I've updated my answer to reflect your updates.

Answer (score 0):

> I am still a bit lost, however, when it comes to actually accessing the different IPs. I believe I need some routes set up, but I'm struggling to figure out how to implement this exactly.

The thing to remember about routing is that **every computer on the route** must know where to send a particular packet.

So if A connects to the RaspPi as 192.168.4.x, and B as 192.168.5.y, then

- A must know that packets to 192.168.5.*/24 go to the 192.168.4.? address of the RaspPi.
- B, when it answers, must know that packets to 192.168.4.*/24 go to the 192.168.5.? address of the RaspPi.

You get this for free if A and B are only connected to the RaspPi, and have the RasPi IP address set as their default gateway. If this is not the case, for example because A and B are also connected to something else, or because you didn't configure `dnsmasq` to advertise the default gateway, then you need to set routes **on A resp. B**.

You can do this either statically directly on A or B, or use DHCP to distribute the routes (first google link for a how-to [here](https://ral-arturo.org/2018/09/12/dhcp-static-route.html), google for more).

In any case, debugging should involve **looking at routes** on both A and B (on Linux, you can use `ip route get 1.2.3.4`, where 1.2.3.4 is the destination address).